# Как добавить в Snackbar ссылку на сайт? (Кликабельную)

Tags: android

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();


        }
    });
```

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сделать для этого кнопку в Snackbar, когда пользователь нажмет эту кнопку то перейдет на сайт.

```
  Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.my_layout), R.string.string_description, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(R.string.name_button, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("www.example.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }).show();
}
```

Comment: Лучше != требуется

Answer (score 0):

Передаёте текст

```
SnackBar.make(view, Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"ссылка\">тыц</a>", ......)
```

И

```
TextView snackMessage = snackBar.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```